# No one's ticket collected on the train: destroy?

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, mussar-ethics, vehicles-transportation

This is a rolloff of this question: [Train ticket not collected: destroy?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12180/719)

---

**IF** one is on a train that is *too packed* for any conductor to go on. Or it is a day where there is bad whether and the conductor doesnt come down and collect **anyone's** tickets, do you have to destroy the ticket?

This is **not** a situation where they accidentally do not collect ***your*** ticket -- they did not collect **any** tickets!

Comment: In my experience, at least once I did not have my ticket collected because of problems with the train system. (The issue was not weather, but a delay of approximately three hours -- time spent stuck on the train.) Would that be a different case, since the lack of collection could be an apology from the railroad?

Comment: @MarthaF. thats exactly the thing I was thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to a source written by Rabbi Yehonossan Gefen I received to a different question, but I believe the answer is relevant

http://www.torah.org/learning/jewish-values/part12.html

In essense, there is no absolute answer, but it is always a good idea to adopt an approach that takes into the consideration that other people will carefully observe view a Jew's actions in monetary matters.